# Will additional lights make an object appear strangely colored?

Tags: light

At one point during Blender Guru's lessons I became a little brave and added 3 point lights.  I added them because I could not see the extremely dark renderview and render.  When I brought back my donut to see how pretty it would be, the sprinkles are colorful but have a dark greyness to them, they look bad now.  Then, the pink icing was perfect.  Now it has kind of an orangish grey color to it and the donut itself looks orange.  Before I delete those lights to see if my pretty donut returns, would adding those lights change the color of my objects?  These 2 images are before and after.  It took me forever to get those lights into there.  I tried an experiment with just a cube and a bunch of lights but nothing happened, it stayed the same color.  Also, in the second pic I have the box in the overview unchecked and the eye unchecked on everything except the donut.  Everything gets rendered no matter how many hide buttons I use.

[[image: pretty donut][1]]
[image: Yucky donut]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think the additional lights are making the objects darker.  I moved everything to a different area, not moving the lights, and the color is coming back.  To me this makes no sense.  More lights should wash it out shouldn't it?

Comment: Check the Strength settings on your lights. I believe if they are negative, they can actually such light out of a scene. Which, while not realistic, makes mathematical sense, if you think about it. Also, you can try to adjust the World properties to change ambient colors without adding or changing lights, as an alternative approach. Finally, you can add your lights to a unique collection so that you can turn them off by hiding it, rather than delete them or move your object away from them. This would make it faster and easier for you to figure out what kind of effect your lights are having.

Comment: Do I find the world option under the Materials Properties tab, drop down the Preview tab then click the last Preview World button?  I thought I saw it elsewhere but that is all that comes up when I search.  Thank you so much.

Comment: No. The World Properties has its own unique tab in the Properties Panel. It looks like a little planet earth icon.

Comment: Is there a way to actually store my preference on the world lighting?  I found the world lighting area and my lighting color was set to a dark brown grey.  I changed it and saved but opening other instances of blender just puts the lighting back to dark.  I checked preferences and lights but I do not think those options are what I need.  Is this just something I need to remember and change?  Thank you for helping me on this.

Comment: You can use "Append" from the File Menu to add your preferred World Settings to your existing blend file. A blend file is actually a folder full of node folders. During the append process, choose the node folder that corresponds to the feature you are trying to transfer to your new file. There is a World Folder, among others. Inside the World folder is a World node. Appending your preferred world node will make it available in your new file. But you will need to select the new world node from the node drop-down menu beside the displayed node name in the Properties Panel before it will display.